# Constructor with bool parameter gets ALWAYS CALLED with _T("...")?

Tags: c++, unicode, constructor

I got a strange beaviour in my program.
I wrote a test which always failed.
While debugging i saw something i don't understand:

I got some multiple Constructors, but this one gets always called if i pass unicode via _T():

```
IsNullable(bool isNullable)
    : m_bIsNullabe(isNullable), Flag(eNullAllowed)
{};
```

And here's my way of calling the constructor:

```
... = new IsNullable(_T("N"));
```

The strange thing is that the bool Constructor above gets always called...
Why is that so? I would be really pleased if someone got a clue!

Greeds,
Clemens

EDIT:

This Constructor should get called:

```
IsNullable(wchar_t isNullable)
    : Flag(eNullAllowed)
{...};
```

Comment: Which constructor should get called?

Comment: added some more information ;)

Comment: `char*` implicitly converts to `bool`. Don't use windows, so not exactly familiar with its character set malarky, but maybe you mean `_T('N')`.

Comment: okay thanks, but why is const wchar_t* implicitly converted into a bool ?

Comment: @ClemensLackner Because the language defines that pointers can be implicitly converted to `bool`. That's the reason you're allowed to write `if(ptr) { /* ptr is not null */ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor that you want to be called takes a `wchar_t` character, not a pointer to a wide string. Call it as:

```
IsNullable( L'N' );
```

Note that I'm not using the `_T` macro because your constructor argument type is `wchar_t` and it is not predicated on whether the `UNICODE` symbol is defined. So there's no need for that macro in this case.

The reason the other constructor is being called is because the string literal, of type `const wchar_t[2]` (assuming the `_T` macro expands to `L"N"`), decays to a `const wchar_t *` which is then implicitly converted to a `bool`.

Comment: okay thanks, but why is const wchar_t* implicitly converted into a bool ?

Comment: Because that is what C++ does.  Pointers are implicitally convertable to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`_T("N")` isn't a `wchar_t`, but a wide string literal, effectively a pointer. There's no conversion from it to a `wchar_t`, but there is a conversion to `bool`. Perhaps you meant

```
new IsNullable(_T('N'))
```